# Python PyQt5: Adding widgets to app layout using the Menu Bar Options

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make GUI application using PyQt5 library that takes a matrix as an input and depending on the option selected by the user, displays the product or sum.

Now the way I want the user to select the operation they want to do (addition or multiplication) is by choosing that option under the Mode Tab in the Menu Bar (which I've coded in already)

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Window(QMainWindow):

     def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 596, 226)
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(596, 226))
        self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(596, 226))
        self.setWindowTitle("Matrix Multiplication")

        # Creating the Menu Bar
        # Defining 'Modes' Menu option
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        modeMenu = mainMenu.addMenu("&Mode")

        # Defining options for 'Mode' Menu and adding them under the 'Mode' Menu
        # Matrix Multiplication Mode
        MatrixMultiplication_FileAction = QtWidgets.QAction("&Matrix Multiplication", self)
        MatrixMultiplication_FileAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+M")
        MatrixMultiplication_FileAction.setStatusTip("Activate Matrix Multiplication Module?")
        MatrixMultiplication_FileAction.triggered.connect(self.MatrixMultiplication_FileAction_Action) #todo
        modeMenu.addAction(MatrixMultiplication_FileAction)

        # Matrix Addition Mode
        MatrixAddition_FileAction = QtWidgets.QAction("&Matrix Addition", self)
        MatrixAddition_FileAction.setShortcut("Ctrl+A")
        MatrixAddition_FileAction.setStatusTip("Activate Matrix Addition Module?")
        MatrixAddition_FileAction.triggered.connect(self.MatrixAddition_FileAction_Action) #todo
        modeMenu.addAction(MatrixAddition_FileAction)

        self.statusBar()
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Ready")

        self.show()

        # Intro Message to explain how to use application
        message = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Introduction",
                                                    "Welcome to the Matrixion App\nTo run calculations, click the Menu Bar\nabove and select desired option")

    # Matrix Multiplication Module
    def MatrixMultiplication_FileAction_Action(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Matrix Multiplication Module is Activated")

        # Defining the layout of all objects in Matrix Multiplication Module
        # Defining font for Header
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)

        # Placing Header
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Matrix Multiplication", self)
        self.WindowHeader.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-4, 0, 601, 41))
        self.WindowHeader.setFont(font)
        self.WindowHeader.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.WindowHeader.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.show()

    # Matrix Addition Module
    def MatrixAddition_FileAction_Action(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Matrix Addition Module is Activated")
        message = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(self, "Houston, we have a problem!", "This feature hasn't been added yet")


def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

I've already used self.show() in my __init__(self): function in which I've coded in the Menu Bar.

I think that calling self.show() again in MatrixMultiplication_FileAction_Action(self): is the problem but I am unable to understand how I can update the GUI (add objects to the layout) using a function that is called when an option from the Menu Bar is selected.

I can assure that the function MatrixMultiplication_FileAction_Action(self) is indeed called as the status tip gets updated. The objects which I've defined however, do not appear.

There is no error message either.

NOTE: The application isn't complete, if i can figure out how to add this label, i can add the other objects as well

Comment: Set a [central widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget) for your Window class to be the parent of the label. Or you may want to use a layout.

Comment: Thanks for your advice alec!
I don't actually fully understand what you mean by making a "central widget", I'm relatively new to PyQt5 so please pardon my inexperience. It would be a huge help if you could elaborate and perhaps supply a code sample
please and thanks

Comment: Sure I'll provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the [Qt Main Window Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework), *creating a main window without a central widget is not supported. You must have a central widget even if it is just a placeholder.* In order to see your QLabel, construct a QWidget to be the central widget of the main window. You may also want to use a layout manager to handle the positions of the widgets.

```
class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(w)

    def MatrixMultiplication_FileAction_Action(self):
        ...
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Matrix Multiplication")
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
```

`self.grid` is a pointer to the QGridLayout that is set on the central widget. So in the MatrixMultiplication function, construct the QLabel without a parent and then add it to the layout.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Okay I think I understand it now. Thank you very much for your help alec!  I'll try this and update my answer as soon as possible.   Once again thank you!

Comment: UPDATE: Okay so the label is now appearing on screen but there is one problem, its expanding to occupy the entire screen and is not resizing despite my best efforts. I do not understand how i can properly and freely position it within this centralwidget as i wish to add several more widgets in this same layout. Additionally, how can i have multiple layouts, as I would prefer to have a separate layout for my Matrix Addition Module

Comment: self.WindowHeader = QtWidgets.QLabel("Matrix Multiplication")
    self.WindowHeader.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-4, 0, 301, 41))
    self.WindowHeader.setFont(font)
    self.WindowHeader.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
    self.WindowHeader.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.WindowHeader, 0, 0)

Comment: @Jay You can add layouts to other layouts. There are [several kinds](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html). It depends what you want to do.